# Isomorphism on a component of tangent space implies local diffeomorphism

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $U$ open set in $\mathbb{C}^{2n}$, $p\in U$.

Let $\phi : U \to \mathbb{C}^n$ be a submersion, i.e. $d\phi$ is surjective at every point.

Assume that $\forall p \in\Re U$, $T_p U$ = $T_p (\Re U) + T_pB$. 
Then along $\Re U$ these two spaces are transverse (by definition)

So $\phi_* \rvert_{T_p\Re U}$ is an isomorphism, therefore $\phi\rvert_{\Re U}$ is a diffeomorphism in a neighbourhood of $p$.

I wrote the whole reasoning because maybe there's some essential detail I'm not noticing... I really don't see why the last implication is true. Can someone help me?

Comment: How can $\phi_*|_{T_pU}$ be an isomorphism? Source and target don't have the same dimension!

Comment: Gosh, I meant $\phi_*\rvert_{T_p \Re U}$, sorry. Edited.

Comment: I guess  $\Re U=U\cap \mathbb R^{2n}$. What is $B$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I get the question right, but if your map does what I think it sould, then you can restrict it to $\Re U$. This new map is a local diffeomorphism from $\Re U$ to $\mathbb C^n$ by means of the local inversion Theorem. The initial map $\phi$ cannot be a local diffeomorphism again for dimension reasons. Since it has surjective differential, it has a local right inverse.

Comment: Oh, just the local inversion theorem then. You're right, that's what transversality is for. Thanks!